# Click function on list filtered by Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

I have a list that I'm using Angular to filter, based on a search:

```html
<div ng-init="psykers = [{name: 'Kairos Fateweaver'},
       {name: 'Pink Horrors(10)'},
       {name: 'Pink Horrors(11-14)'},
       {name: 'Pink Horrors(15 or more)'},
       {name: 'Sorcerer (lvl 1)'},
       {name: 'Sorcerer (lvl 2)'},
       {name: 'Sorcerer (lvl 3)'}]">
</div>
```

This information gets displayed in the following paragraph with a class on it:

```html
<label>Begin entering a psyker's name here:
  <input id="psykerSearch" ng-model="searchText">
</label>
<p class="psykerResult" ng-repeat="psyker in psykers | filter:searchText">
  {{psyker.name}}
</p>
```

I am trying to assign a click event to any of the text that shows up. It works the first time, and if I change my search, it works one more time, but then if I change my search again (which of course generates new results), it fails to recognize the text at all as a click event. I think it is not recognizing the class of the updated list. I have some fades on keyup, and I tried updating a variable to recognize it there, but to no luck.

Here's the keyup code:

```js
var psykerResult = $('.psykerResult');

// SHOW PSYKERS BASED ON SEARCH 

$('#psykerSearch').on("change keyup paste", function() {

  psykerResult = $('.psykerResult');

  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    psykerResult.fadeOut(500);
  } else {
    psykerResult.fadeIn(500);
  }
}); // End Keyup
```

And This is what happens when a user clicks. It matches the text clicked on with information stored in an array and displays it in a div. Then it brings down some drop down menus:

```js
psykerResult.click(function() {

  // 1. disable input and hide psykers

  $('#psykerSearch').prop('disabled', true);
  psykerResult.hide();

  // 2. match psyker & display profile

  for (var i = 0; i < psykers.length; i++) {

    if (psykers[i].name == $(this).text().trim()) {

      chosenPsyker = psykers[i];

      psykerProfile += '<h2>' + chosenPsyker.name + '</h2>' + '<p>Warp Charge: ' + chosenPsyker.warpCharge + '</p>' + '<p>Mastery Level: ' + chosenPsyker.mastery + '</p>' + '<p class="notes">' + '<label for="notes">Notes: </label><textarea id="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>' + '</p>';

      $('#psykerProfiles').html(psykerProfile);
    }
  }

  // 3. display power dropdown lists

  for (var i = 0; i < chosenPsyker.power.length; i++) {
    $('#' + chosenPsyker.power[i]).fadeIn(500);
  }
}); //End psyker click
```

Comment: get rid of all that jQuery ... take jQuery right of page completely and use event directives like `ng-click`, `ng-keyup` along with `ngAnimate` to do what you are doing. Strongly suggest you read [thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: @charlietfl is completely correct, `ng-init` is more so on the right path but probably should also be avoided as well for instantiating an array that be done within the controller.

Comment: @charlietfl At this point, my whole page is largely based in jquery, and it would not make sense to change it all.

Comment: then maybe you should ask yourself why you are using angular. If it's merely as a template engine then it is a big overkill frought with lots of conflict potential and there are other much lighter template engines that aren't full frameworks and don't manipulate the dom the way angular does

Comment: @charlietfl I am using it merely for filtering the search. Would you happen to know a better alternative?

Comment: there are numerous filter/sort plugins you could use...or start converting the jQuery to angular

Comment: @charlietfl I used list.js and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your desire if for after clicking one of the items in the list, but I've created a simple example of what you can do with much simpler Angular code that keeps the presentation within the HTML and logic (not much in this case) within the controller.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label>Begin entering a psyker's name here:
    <input id="psykerSearch" ng-model="searchText" ng-disabled="chosenPsyker">
  </label>
  <p class="psykerResult" ng-repeat="psyker in psykers | filter:searchText">
    <a href="#" ng-bind="psyker.name" ng-click="psykerClicked(psyker)"></a>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <h2 ng-bind="chosenPsyker.name"></h2>
  <p>Warp Charge: <span ng-bind="chosenPsyker.warpCharge"></span></p>
  <p>Mastery Level:  <span ng-bind="chosenPsyker.mastery"></span></p>
  <p class="notes">
    <label for="notes">Notes: </label>
    <textarea id="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  </p>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.psykers = [
    {name: 'Kairos Fateweaver'       , warpCharge: 1, mastery: 11},
        {name: 'Pink Horrors(10)'        , warpCharge: 2, mastery: 12},
        {name: 'Pink Horrors(11-14)'     , warpCharge: 3, mastery: 13},
        {name: 'Pink Horrors(15 or more)', warpCharge: 4, mastery: 14},
        {name: 'Sorcerer (lvl 1)'        , warpCharge: 5, mastery: 15},
        {name: 'Sorcerer (lvl 2)'        , warpCharge: 6, mastery: 16},
        {name: 'Sorcerer (lvl 3)'        , warpCharge: 7, mastery: 17}
    ];

    $scope.psykerClicked = function(psyker) {
      $scope.chosenPsyker = psyker;
    }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/W5mVlpIiHw7FqgO8LuHx)

Comment: I ended up using list.js and ditching angular altogether, but your solution looks like it could be helpful for anyone who wants to use Angular, so I selected it as the best answer. Thank you for your time and effort. Even though I will not be using this, it is nice to see how this would be done in Angular.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  I started out using jQuery and then switched to using Angular; I found once I got accustomed to the new way of doing things that development time going way down.

Comment: I'm new to Angular. My first thought is that jQuery is maybe more flexible due to the massive amount of plugins available. Wouldn't you miss out on that with Angular? Or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: There may be more plugins for jQuery (most likely but not sure one way or another) but there are plenty of modules available for Angular.  I can't think of anything in Angular that I've wished for and someone already hadn't done it and shared their code.